# Order a stacked barplot (ggplot2) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

atm I try to finialize a couple of graph's. One thing which does not work so far, is to order the bar plots (the bars). This is an example of my code:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                         district=c("1","1","2","3","2","1","1","2","3","2"),
                         f1=c("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","2","3")
)


df$f1 <- as.numeric(df$f1)


df |> 
  dplyr::count(district, f1) |> 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n), .by = district) |> 
  ggplot(aes(pct, district, fill = f1)) +
  geom_col()
```

What I want to do now, is to sort the barplots by pct (1st bar should be highest pct in f1 "1"). I tried different approuces, but nothing worked sofar!

Thanks for helping!

Best regards,
k